# ios google api issue

Tags: ios, google-maps, mkmapview

I need to add a very common Google functionality to an iPhone app I am developing. The idea is that the user is presented with a TextBox where he can write an address (i.e.: "Amsterdam av)". The thing is that I want to add some "help" for him, se when he writes a street name, the app will show him a list of partial matches, like google Maps does here:

[sample http://www.timotteo.com.ar/google.png](http://www.timotteo.com.ar/google.png)

I can´t find the exact class in the google API. It doesn't need to be as fast as google's own search, maybe the user can write "amst" and press a search button, to be presented with a list of partial matches. The API I'm looking for show return in some way a list with posibilities. All I could find for now where method that gives you the lat/long when you feed it with a specific address. Does somebody know what combination of methods/classes I should use? Maybe some example?

Txs in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actully what I was looking for is this:

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=amsterdam%201543&output=xml&oe=utf8&sensor=true&hl=es&gl=ar

That URL returns and XML with all the autocomplete options. All I have to do is parse that XML and voila! There I have my list.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for the autocomplete feature of the Places API: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete

This won't autocomplete for all addresses or streets, but rather for businesses, notable landmarks, etc.

If you want autocomplete for street addresses, I do not believe that is available through any documented APIs. That doesn't mean workarounds don't exist, but they may depend on more details about your use case. (For example, if you only care about a narrow geographic area, it may be possible to simply have a list of all the streets in your own database and handle the AJAX call yourself.)